# Dynamically create html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a website, I have an API which extracts a list of products and gives me a JSON file which has all the info I need. What I wanted to achieve is to have a separate page created for each of the product - dynamically (since the JSON file will be changing). Is that possible with javascript/html?

Thank you

Comment: This is done all the time. Most web sites with dynamic work this way these days.

Comment: You probably want to look up `slugs`.  Here's a starter article: https://itnext.io/whats-a-slug-f7e74b6c23e0

Comment: The best thing to do is to look at a framework like Django, Laravel, Symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. This is how all retail websites are created.

I suggest you start learning some javascript framework like ReactJS or Angular. In short, after the JSON is received from the server, it is passed to -what we call- a component as props (properties). The component holds some jsx or html that forms the "skeleton" of the user interface. The objects in the JSON (I assume each object is a product), fill the skeleton.

This is an example of a very very very basic structure for one single product. You can use a `for` loop or the `map` method to iterate over your JSON so you can display each product's details in the following format:

In the following snippet, props could look like this `{productImage:"imgur.com/blabal.png",productTitle:"Product X",price:3000}`

```
function product(props){

return(
<div className="product-container">
<img className="product-image" src={props.productImage}
<span className="product-title">{props.productTitle}</span>
<span className="product-price">{props.price}$</span>
......
</div>
)
}
```

Each product will have its own object with its own `productImage`, `productTitle` and `price` among other things you choose to add.

So you'll have 1,000 products (1,000 objects). You'll pass the products one by one to the above snippet (as props), and it'll display all of the products. Instead of writing 1,000 snippets for each product.

Obviously I can't teach you ReactJS in one answer. I highly recommend you look into [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). You can find many tutorials on Youtube. What you're looking to do is very easy.

Comment: Thank you so much, will look into React. Sorry this must be dumb question, but when a user clicks on a product, will React create a new HTML page and store it in the server? or how does that work.

Comment: The "skeleton" will be hosted (stored) on a server. So just one snippet of code. The information of the product is filled in on the user's side (after they request to view a product). At no point will there be 1,000 copies on the hosting server.

Comment: @Forged let me know if you need anything else :) if not, I recommend that you accept the answer. So other people can benefit from the answer also.

Comment: yes that was the answer I was looking for, just accepted sorry!